# Jython: Parameterize values in quotes

Tags: python, jython-2.5

how to parameter values in quotes in jython, this is my calling method :

BaseSTSSchedulerTask.**init**(self, Test(testId, “Get Service Group by ID”), hostPort, ‘/SchServices/api/servicegroup/9999′, HEADERS)

I want to replace the value 9999 with a variable which is returned from another method., 
like id= Data.getID().

I tried doing this ‘/SchServices/api/servicegroup/’+id, but it does not help . Any idea how to handle this ?

Comment: Careful -- Your quotes look funny.  Are you sure they're ascii single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just fixed this by doing : ‘/SchServices/api/servicegroup/’+**self.id**, "id" is a built in function in jython. so self.id  is now a instance variable.